# Assert_failure src/lib_shell/chain_validator.ml:182:8

Tags: node, archive-node

I see the following error on one of the nodes

```
Jan 27 08:06:02 - validator.block: Block BLRT7WujAf4ppbT7eVL6mdSvm63a1Yzn7yYNt4H7mytHnzCqbNA successfully validated
Jan 27 08:06:02 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:05:52-00:00, treated in 106us, completed in 9.812s
Jan 27 08:06:02 - lwt-worker.validator-chain_NetXdQprcVkpa: Worker validator-chain_NetXdQprcVkpa:
Jan 27 08:06:02 - lwt-worker.validator-chain_NetXdQprcVkpa: Failed with Exception: "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/chain_validator.ml:182:8"
```

I'm running `mainnet-2020-january`

The issue is that I see requests for blocks being pushed but the current head is not being updated.

Here are some relevant logs

```
Jan 27 08:08:35 - validator.block: Block BL3x6EA2vPzVu9hK31iQxfU8Ds7NqPx1UDw7VZTYHQUiTKmEygh successfully validated
Jan 27 08:08:35 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:08:33-00:00, treated in 139us, completed in 1.842s
Jan 27 08:09:35 - validator.block: Block BL5rH9QejQVusU9mMGCQWTLF3ndgVd6w7735kw5C2U7HHvtqHBv successfully validated
Jan 27 08:09:35 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:09:34-00:00, treated in 463us, completed in 1.325s
Jan 27 08:10:35 - validator.block: Block BM1ivav9MgKii5shFR5poKaxUT4dDX3oS7kgGfRmfAC1rD85fsT successfully validated
Jan 27 08:10:35 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:10:34-00:00, treated in 102us, completed in 1.590s
Jan 27 08:11:19 - validator.peer: Worker terminated [validator-peer_44]
Jan 27 08:11:35 - validator.block: Block BMFDTTYJE1XLoPXjZaim1twpBwoaCjCPk6c2j6D2NLWXTUCYNPH successfully validated
Jan 27 08:11:35 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:11:34-00:00, treated in 692us, completed in 595ms
Jan 27 08:12:37 - validator.block: Block BKiRRbdaoizo1mwcriP98cADXCKbsoBgWNT8Lxs8QVu7THsLuf4 successfully validated
Jan 27 08:12:37 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:12:35-00:00, treated in 361us, completed in 1.857s
Jan 27 08:13:42 - validator.block: Block BMM36JVnKZ48bhFrDbBiHnMxUz3trEtjU1tyoytcYDLUiSgftqA successfully validated
Jan 27 08:13:42 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-27T08:13:41-00:00, treated in 349us, completed in 996ms
Jan 27 08:13:42 - validator.peer: Worker terminated [validator-peer_42]
```

***P.S.*** Please let me know if you need any further details, I'd be happy to update the question with more details

Comment: You should absolutely file this as a bug on gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues If you look at the source code for that line number, it clearly states "this should not happen"

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/lib_shell/chain_validator.ml#L182

Comment: Please update your question with the link to the gitlab issue thanks!